# Sharepoint client.PostAsync("Url", null) Gets 401 unauthorized error REST API Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio, sharepoint-rest-api

I am developing a cross mobile app using Xamarin and I am trying to post some items to a SharePoint List.

I have created a windows form app just to test the SharePoint Rest API and it is working good, I have the following code:

```
        var username = "user";
        var password = "pass";
        var domain = "domain";

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        HttpResponseMessage content = client.PostAsync("http://mysite/_api/contextinfo", null).Result;
```

the `content` variable (`HttpResponseMessage`) returns me a `200` Status code, which is `OK` and everything is working.

However I have the same code in my `Xamrin Froms` but it is not working it throws me a `401 unauthorized` error

this is my Xamarin Code

```
    private async void BtnRestApi_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var username = "user";
         var password = "pass";
         var domain = "domain";

         var handler = new HttpClientHandler
         {
             Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
         };

          var client = new HttpClient(handler);

         HttpResponseMessage content = client.PostAsync("http://mysite/_api/contextinfo", null).Result;
    }
```

and this is the error

[image]

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/issues/25

Answer (score 1):

This is example PostAsync [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin), [PostAsync - 401 Unauthorized](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/issues/25):

```
var item = await FirebaseClient
                  .Child("someTable")
                  .WithAuth(Auth.FirebaseToken)
                  .PostAsync(someObject, false);
```